# open pdf file C# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have some customers in a gridview. When I click on the customers I can get their names in a textbox. There is also a corresponding pdf document which should also be available if the user desires.

My problem is that I need to know who to open a pdf document using C# and asp.net. I have to use a variable name as the name of pdf document, for example when the click on a button "open variable CustomerName.pdf".

I need to open a pdf file in a new window for viewing

**thanks**
 this works
 asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/customerUnit/Customer.pdf" Target="_blank">HyperLink

But I want to pass the pdf file as a variable "Customer.pdf" should be "VaribleCustmer.pdf"

Comment: When you say open? in what way? to launch the PDF for the user to open? if so just do a hyperlink or Response.Redirect to that file in question. the browser will either open it or prompt the user to open it in a download dialog

Answer (score 1):

I agree with `@Ahmed` from the comments, you shouldn't over-think this:

- Simply link to the `CustomerName.pdf` if your using a hyperlink.
- Simply redirect to `the CustomerName.pdf` if your using a button

---

> But I want to pass the pdf file as a variable "Customer.pdf" should be "VaribleCustmer.pdf"

Asp Markup:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" 
               runat="server" Target="_blank">
```

Code behind:

```
var pdfFile = "Customer.pdf"; //or VaribleCustmer.pdf
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl= String.Format("~/customerUnit/{0}", pdfFile);
```